# What do I do when I get error 401 with Banuba Video Editor?

Tags: android, video, server, editor

I get this error from the server - error 401: Unauthorized.
Our team could not find a problem on our side.
How do we fix it and what is causing this error?

And we did not find a solution to the problem on your website.
Could you help us out here?

Answer (score 0):

The error is connected to you not using the correct credentials for accessing our custom maven repository.
Please, note that **authentication is required in any case** (regardless of read-only or download-only access), so the username and the GitHub token with read-only packages are still required.

For the most up to date ones, feel free to refer to the following gradle file from our example: https://github.com/Banuba/ve-sdk-android-integration-sample/blob/main/build.gradle#L23.

Thank you!